# What's the motivation to fit in log-log scale?

Tags: fitting, curve-fitting, logarithm

Consider a signal that obeys: $y \propto exp(x)$. Here a semi-log scale makes sense. Or even a case where $y \propto x^k$ a semi log scale will do the work.

Why is there any motivation to scale into log-log scale. Is it just for case where $y^m \propto x^k$?

It's not clear from the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot#Relation_with_monomials) as well. It's obviously widely used, but I don't get why.

Comment: Mostly because $\log(-\log((0,1))) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so it is useful for modeling probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second claim in the first paragraph is wrong.

A semilog scale  for the conditional (on $x$) relationship $\mu_Y=cx^k$ does not linearize that relationship. Taking logs of both sides the relationship linearly relates the log of the conditional mean of $Y$ to the log of $x$ -- so you need a log-log scale for it .... $\log(\mu_Y)=\log(c) + k\log x$.

That alone would be sufficient reason to use it.